# How to output a variable inside a Listbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've looked up on the net different guides on how to do what I want to, but i didn't find any solution that I could understand.
What I want to do is to display the content stored in any variable in a Listbox in Tkinter.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

test = Listbox(window, width=28, heigh=10, font=("Helvetica", 14), state="disabled")
test.grid(row=0, column=0)

for x in range(30):
    test.insert(END, x)

window.mainloop()
```

If you think the best solution to my problem would be reached with something different from a Listbox it's fine anyway.
Thank you in advance

Comment: By "print" do you mean "insert into the listbox"? I can't imagine a single resource on the web that covers the listbox without showing how to do this.

Comment: Of course it's written, the resources say to do as I've modified the question but it still doesn't work and it doesn't return me any error.

Answer (score 0):

Your listbox is disabled, which means you can't insert or delete items. Set the state to `"normal"` before inserting.

Comment: I need a write only Listbox though

Comment: @Nicolò: you can set the state to `disabled` after you are done inserting values. Though, that doesn't actually affect "write-only" status, since the only way for a user to "write" into your listbox is through code you've written.